# Data push in Android from a Java server

Tags: java, android, sockets, client, serversocket

I am developing an Android application that connects to a Java server (with sockets). How I can do to make the server send data to clients when some data is changed on the server?

Answer (score 2):

i would recommend using googles push services:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

that way you don't need a static connection to the server, but just fetch new data from the server if the client receives a push notification (or- if the information is not too big, you can add it as payload to the push notification).

alternatively if you want to support multiple platforms you could also take a look at services like urban airship:

http://urbanairship.com/

Comment: I can recommend to have a look at google's push services also